# Is the .should('exist') assertion redundant on Cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, assertion

Let's consider the case where I need to assert if an element exists. There are 2 possible ways of doing this in cypress:

```
1) cy.get('button').contains('Save')
2) cy.get('button').contains('Save').should('exist')
```

In both cases the test will fail if the 'Save' button not exist.

What are the reasons apart from maybe better code readability/maintainability that I should add the **.should('exist')** to my cypress tests?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For your usecase of asserting whether an element exists, they are indeed redundant.

`.contains()` yields a DOM element and according to [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Yields), `.should` yields the same element it was given as an input. There are some exceptions when .should yields different element (as you can see in the documentation) but in case of using `should('exist')`, they are really redundant

As you mentioned, I personally also prefer adding `should` for better readability. Actually I prefer `.should('be.visible')` because of following scenario - when an element is hidden or is pushed out of the screen because of some CSS issues, it doesn't exist from user perspective. But..

`cy.get('button').contains('Save')` - passes test

`cy.get('button').contains('Save').should('exist')` - passes test

`cy.get('button').contains('Save').should('be.visible')` - fails test

Comment: but do we really want to have to use `scrollIntoView` for elements which are simply out of the browser's visible viewport?

Comment: assuming the BDD gherkin expresses that the page should auto-scroll which would otherwise leave the element off screen. thus the implicit `exists` of `cy.get` can be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, until v4.0 is released (and [this PR](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/3268) is merged), you need to chain `should('exist')` assertion if you chain any negative assertions yourself. This is because the default `should('exist')` assertion [is skipped when you chain your own assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Effect-on-default-DOM-assertions).

Not necessary for positive assertions because they won't pass on non-existent elements.

Also see [Implicit should 'exist' assertion is not being applied on cy.get() when other assertion.](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/205)

Below, the element `.first-item` does not exist but the assertion passes:

```js
describe('test', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        cy.get('.first-item').should('not.have.class', 'is-selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From my test,

```
cy.get('button').contains('Save').should('exist')
```

is not redundant.

It's true that, if it contains `Save`, your test is successful. If it doesn't, your test fails with the desired reason description. In that aspect, `should('exist')` is redundant.

However, if you do `cy.get('button').contains('Save')`, and the button exists, you only get a grey step which means the step is executed without error. But it does not show a green `assert` badge, because you don't have an assertion there.

So I could suggest removing line 1) and keep line 2).

Then if it passes, you get a green `assert` badge. If it fails, it actually fails at `contains('Save')` part rather than `should` part. But anyway, you get red error with meaningful error messages.

Although, I do agree with @Durkomatko that 'be.visible' is better if you do want it to show on the page.

Comment: This sounds incorrect. What would an example HTML be?

Comment: I also find it more expressive to tell that this `contains` is an assertion and not an action leading to the assertion. Following the Arrange - Act - Assert pattern for instance, it seems important to enlight parts of the test failing beceause of the Act part, or because of the Assert part. And Cypress indeed add an `assert` tag, helping to do this. BTW, I'm clearly not a test expert.